# ADW1205HLW latching relay heating issue

Tags: relay, heat, mosfet-driver, latching

I want to take the advantage of latching relay to remove power dissipation from the circuit.

I am also using ADW1205HLW dual latching coil relay but faces an issue of heating even after set or reset pulse.

I have used 1k in series with mmbt3904 at base and collector connected to set coil with flyback diode and same circuit for reset coil.

Please let me know where am I wrong here . I have tested this relay with push button switch and working fine but with transistor driver I am facing the issue of heating continue even after latch (set) of the relay.

Please find the schematic and datasheet attached for the reference.
[ADW1205HLW , bistable two coil latching relay](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e_download/control/relay/power/catalog/mech_eng_dw.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Hi @irfan, please provide a schematic and datasheets for your relay and transistor.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Added the data

Comment: What is heating? If both set and reset transistors are off, where is current flowing?

Comment: Heating in terms of body temperature of relay starts increasing with time at specified load and keep on increasing. One state always kept on either set or reset. We either make load on using set or either make it load off using reset so both transistors will not get off at the same time. Let me know if i understand it clearly or not.

Comment: You said "...so both transistors will not get off at the same time". I interpret that to mean one transistor is ALWAYS on. That's wrong. A latching relay should only require a short pulse on SET or RESET to change state. The relay is supposed to _latch_ into the new state with no further current into either coil. If you continue to power one of the coils it's going to get hot.

Comment: I mean to say the state not transistors , we have set the 30ms and 100ms in firmware pulse width . Now I understood your question clearly , so when both transistors off after applied of pulses I don't know where the current will go ? May be due to this little bit of heating continues , can you please guide me for this ?

Comment: @RandyNuss:  As not required continuous current so when both transistor off so no issue of current , secondly we have resolved the issue by applying 45ms pulse width and now only minor heating observed which is acceptable at the load tested.

Comment: Thanks all for the support